# How to create a new page in prestashop admin panel?

Tags: php, admin, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

how to create a new page in prestashop admin panel? I tried using creating a new admin controller file and in that set the template path and i created a menu using admin panel and there i mentioned the controller class name for that menu. when i try to open that menu it always shows that controller not found. can anyone help me, how to create a new page in prestashop admin panel? am using PS 1.5 version.

```
 <?php
class AdminPageController extends AdminController {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();
 $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'mypage.tpl');
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by new page? Design a new backoffice theme or add new menu item that will show your new page?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

create controllers/admin/AdminPageController.php with the follwing content:

```
    class AdminPageController extends AdminController
    {
        public function initContent()
        {
            parent::initContent();
            $smarty = $this->context->smarty;

            $smarty->assign('test', 'test1');

        }
    }
```

Delete: /cache/class_index.php

Create: admin\themes\default\template\controllers\page\content.tpl

```
zzz{$test}zzz
```

At BackOffice -> Administration -> Menus -> [Add New]:

```
Name: Page
Class: AdminPage
Parent: Catalog
```

Click the [Save] button and the menu item should appear at the "Catalog" menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It gives me an page to show content. exactly what I am looking for.. really helpful for me.. Thanks Again !!!

Comment: please, this works for me, but how do i delete the same page from the menus ??

Comment: i created the page successfully using this tutorial, please how do i remove it completely from the admin page and menu

Comment: Delete the 2 created files, and remove it from BackOffice -> Administration -> Menus

Comment: Yes, it is supported in 1.6 as well.

Answer (score -1):

it will be like this

```
class AdminPageController extends AdminController
{
    public function __construct()    
    {    
         parent::__construct();        
    }

    public function initContent()    
    {
        parent::initContent();       
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'mypage.tpl');   
    }
}
```

Comment: _PS_THEME_DIR_.'mypage.tpl' path not work in admin themes>
_PS_THEME_DIR_ refer to frontend theme path not admin