# Prestashop: How to submit data from adminpanel template to Admin Controller?

Tags: ajax, controller, admin, form-submit, prestashop

I'm trying to make a custom page in the adminpanel of Prestashop where the shopowner can fill in his upcoming events that will appear in a column in the header.tpl page. The templates and controller are working so far, with a structure based on an answer here at Stack Overflow:

[How to create a new page in prestashop admin panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490217/how-to-create-a-new-page-in-prestashop-admin-panel)

Now I have made in the content.tpl (with the added custom JavaScript and CSS files) the form with the input fields. The next step is to send it to the controller to save it in the database. But I'm stuck this part. I can't find how I can nicely submit the form to the controller. First I tried it with an Ajax function but I couldn't find the right way. Also without Ajax no success.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
async: true,
cache: false,
dataType : "json",
data:{
    processEvents: true,
    ajax: 'true',
    controller: 'AdminEvents',
    token: static_token
    },
    //success: function(jsonData){
        //}
    });
```

**This is an example of an Ajax function that I tried. My questions:**

- How does other tpl or js files receive the baseUri, where is that
  variable set?
- What is the function of the ?rand date and time in that line? A kind
  of security token?
- What is the url of the controller? Also the url when I use

  I guess the processEvents : true and Ajax : true is for security
  reasons and to check if the form is submitted by Ajax or not?

  Why is it necessary to send the controller name?

  Where does the token come from?

**Questions about the controller:**

- Which (Prestashop default functions) can or do need to use? For
  example:

  ```
  if (Tools::isSubmit('name')){
  ```

  etc.

  ```
  if (Tools::getValue('create_account')){
  ```

  etc.
- Can I use that functions anywhere or maybe only in an Init function?

A lot of questions, feel free to answer only a part of it, I just need a good push in the right direction, searching and reading in the online documentation and on the internet doesn't brought me the solution and brainwashed me a little.

EDIT:

I made a little progress by myself:

- *Where does the token come from?*
- *What is the url of the controller? Also the url when I use*

With the tools getAdminTokenLite and the controller name I generated the controller url:

```
$token = '?controller=AdminEvents&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminEvents');
```

The url to post to is the token plus the domain, admin directory and index.php.

With the tool getValue I get the POST data like in PHP with $_POST["name"].

```
Tools::getValue('event_name')
```

So its working but I guess it can be better with other Presta default tools.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's very late to answer you, but for sure it will help other mates with same problem.

Here is an example about how to implement ajax calls in Prestashop 1.6 on Admin panel using ANY Controller from BackOffice (if you want also, you can use ajax.php controller, but I'm using for this AdminImportController() )

tpl part:

```
$('#mybtn').click(function(e) {

    var data = $('#datalist').val();

    // Ajax call with secure token 
    $.post( "{$current|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}&token=       {$token|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}",
             { ajax: true, action: "MyFunction", mydata: data } );

            });
```

And in admin controller side:

```
    public function ajaxProcessMyFunction()
    {
        // Get param
        $mydata = (int)Tools::getValue('mydata');

        $answer = 0;

        if( $mydata > 0 ) {

            $this->importProfList = Db::getInstance()->executeS(
                "SELECT * FROM  .... LIMIT 1"
            );
            ...
            $answer = $someOperationResult;
        }

        // Response
        die(Tools::jsonEncode(array(
          'answer' => htmlspecialchars($answer)
        )));
  }
```

Tested and working like a charm.

Regards