# Prestashop menu tab, that opens an iframe(Backoffice)

Tags: iframe, module, tabs, prestashop

I'm working on a project for creating a prestashop module that creates a custom tab at the back office and by pressing it, it opens an iframe. I have created the tab but at the menu bar at the backoffice. But i dont know how open an iframe by pressing it. 
Can you help me out please?

This is my module's code:

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class Mytab extends Module
{
    // PLIROFORIES TOY AYTHOR
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'Mytab';
        $this->tab = 'Administration';
        $this->version = 1.5;
        $this->author = 'Sergio Kagiema';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        //$this->tabParentName = 'AdminTools';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My Tab');
        $this->description = $this->l('Module makes a tab at BackEnd');
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('My Tab'))      
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');

    } //END OF  PLIROFORIES TOY AYTHOR



    //INSTALL TOY MODULE
    public function install()
    {
        $parent_tab = new Tab();
        foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang)
            $parent_tab->name [$lang['id_lang']] = 'Tab';
        $parent_tab->class_name = 'Tab';
        $parent_tab->id_parent = 0;
        $parent_tab->module = $this->name;
        $parent_tab->add();
        if (!parent::install()
            || !$this->installModuleTab('MyTabsController', array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'))=>'My Tab'), $parent_tab->id)
        )
            return false;  
        return true;
    }



    //UNISTALL TOY MODULE
    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall()
            || !$this->uninstallModuleTab('MyTab')
            || !$this->uninstallModuleTab('MyTabsController'))
            return false;  
        return true;
    }   


    private function installModuleTab($tabClass, $tabName, $idTabParent)
    {
        $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName($idTabParent);       
        $idTab = $idTabParent;
        $pass = true ;
        @copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/logo.gif', _PS_IMG_DIR_.'t/'.$tabClass.'.gif');
        $tab = new Tab();
        $tab->name = $tabName;
        $tab->class_name = $tabClass;
        $tab->module = $this->name;
        $tab->id_parent = $idTab;
        $pass = $tab->save();
        return($pass);
    }

    private function uninstallModuleTab($tabClass)
    {
        $pass = true ;
        @unlink(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'t/'.$tabClass.'.gif');
        $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName($tabClass);
        if($idTab != 0)
        {
            $tab = new Tab($idTab);
            $pass = $tab->delete();
        }
        return($pass);
    }            


}
```

?>

This is my controller's code at my contoroller/admin file:

```
<?php

class AffiliatesTabsController extends AdminController
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();      
    }

    /**
    *  Assign template vars related to page content
    *  @see FrontController::initContent()
    */
    public function initContent() 
    {   parent::initContent();

        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'/MyTab.tpl');
        //$smarty = $this->context->smarty;
        //$smarty->assign('test', 'test1');
        // include(dirname(__FILE__).'/jQ.tpl');


    }
}
```

?>

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching for similar things today and find out.

Controller:

```
class AffiliatesTabsController extends ModuleAdminController
{   
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('MyTab.tpl');
    }   
}
```

Then move MyTab.tpl into

```
prestashop\modules\mytab\views\templates\admin\affiliatestabs\
```

MyTab.tpl:

```
<iframe src="webpage url">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an admin template for frontoffice use, that won't work.

This solution here works for me:

[How to create a new page in prestashop admin panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490217/how-to-create-a-new-page-in-prestashop-admin-panel)

Edit: additions after comments below:

After you created the the AdminAffiliatesController.php file in controllers\admin folder you create the template file here:

**admin\themes\default\template\controllers\adminaffiliates\content.tpl**

In that content.tpl file you can create your iframe or whatever.

Every output that you create in the controller or default values that you wan't to use or display in your template do you need to assign in the controller like this:

```
$title_of_page = "Welcome at this page!";

$smarty->assign('title_of_page', 'title_of_page');
```

In your template:

```
<h1>{$title_of_page}</h1>
```

Comment: I want the iframe opened at the Backoffice. Not at the frontoffice.thnx!

Comment: Well your link didn't help that much. :/

Comment: You are doing this: `$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'/MyAffiliatesates.tpl');` Then you are setting a front office template in the root of your of your themefolder.

Comment: OK but what about this: $smarty->assign('test', 'test1'); ? Should I do with it?

Comment: Still I get the message "Controller not found". I think the problem might be at my module. For not "calling" my controller.

Comment: Did you delete the cache file?  /cache/class_index.php Otherwise start from scratch and follow exactly the steps from the first link in my answer.

Comment: I figure it out. The "Controller not found" error appeared because I had  different class name from the installModuleTab and uninstallModuleTab.

Comment: Now i get this error message: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException'..."