# how to delete page and remove menu created in prestashop backoffice

Tags: php, admin, prestashop

I created a new page in the prestashop back office following the answer provided here

[How to create a new page in prestashop admin panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490217/how-to-create-a-new-page-in-prestashop-admin-panel/19501471#19501471)

I mistakenly created another and had issues, most of the new ones came up blank and the old one now displays blank.

How do i remove the menus from the page as they do not appear
  in the preference -> Menu page
    because i created them under the catalog tab ?
I really need to delete all the menus, i have already deleted the associated files.

Comment: can you please provide us with a link? It's a bit hard to understand what you did wrong and what you want to undo.

Comment: i want to delete the menu i added under the catalog tab in the backoffice that's all

Comment: what version of prestashop are we talking about?

Comment: prestashop version 1.5

Answer (score 0):

From the Menu page, click details button from the catalog tab with the + icon in the actions column, you can find your menu created under the catalog tab from there