# Prestashop 1.6 - Back Office - Smarty - Creating a module that makes a simple blank page?

Tags: module, admin, prestashop

I am trying to add some functionality to my shop and have spent the past two days trying to come to grasp with how smarty actually works within prestashop or rather in general.

I have so far made a module that can install, on install it creates a tab on the left menu, I can click on the tab and it will load the controller but this is where i get stuck... I can't figure out how to display custom content within that state.

What i would like is very simple, just a paragraph of text and a button. When clicking the button i will do a few things and record a few things then show the results as a simple report.

So for starters... I'd like to create the page with the paragraph and button.

So i have created a folder in the module diretory called priceupdate

Inside of this there is:

```
/priceupdate.php

<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class PriceUpdate extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'priceupdate';
        $this->tab = 'quick_bulk_update';
        $this->version = '0.8';
        $this->author = 'Me';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Pricing Update');
        $this->description = $this->l('Adds functionality relating to maintaining product my prices.');  

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you would like to uninstall?');

    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install()
            || !$this->installModuleTab('AdminPricingUpdate', array(1=>'Pricing Update'), 0))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall()
            || !$this->uninstallModuleTab('AdminPricingUpdate', array(1=>'Pricing  Update'), 0))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private function installModuleTab($tabClass, $tabName, $idTabParent)

    {    
        $tab = new Tab();

        $tab->name = $tabName;

        $tab->class_name = $tabClass;

        $tab->module = $this->name;

        $tab->id_parent = $idTabParent;

        if(!$tab->save())

            return false;

        return true;

    }

    private function uninstallModuleTab($tabClass)

    {       
        $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName($tabClass);

        if($idTab != 0)

        {

            $tab = new Tab($idTab);

            $tab->delete();

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

}
?>
```

And

```
/controllers/admin/AdminPricingUpdateController.php

<?php
class AdminPricingUpdateController extends AdminController
{

    public function __construct()

    {

        $this->lang = (!isset($this->context->cookie) || !is_object($this->context->cookie)) ? intval(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) : intval($this->context->cookie->id_lang);

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function display(){

        parent::display();

    }

    public function renderList() {

        return $this->context->smarty->fetch(dirname(__FILE__).'/content.tpl');

    }   
}
?>
```

This works however where I am stuck relates to the content.tpl part. What goes inside of this the content.tpl file in order to get it to make a blank page of content within the content area of the admin section?

I've looked through the manual and spent countless hours on forums looking though questions, tried to figure it out by breaking down other modules but i've found it too complex to really understand what is what.

If anyone could help me to understand this or point me to a source of info on this specific subject then it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490217/how-to-create-a-new-page-in-prestashop-admin-panel/19501471)

If you need "a blank page of content within the content area of the admin section" you need to make the content.tpl blank.

Note in my example that you do not have to set the name of the template if it's called "content.tpl".

Comment: Thanks for your input, I really appreciate it! However, if I leave the content.tpl blank it just makes a white page with nothing. I want to add content to a new page within the actual content area in the back office (so like where all the dash information is displayed - all the info but with a little button and some words). I did check out what you have said and it looks like a modification to prestashop to add a menu. I do understand basically how it works but the only problem is not if i have that in my controller it just loads a white page too... content.tpl is in `modules/priceupdate/`

Comment: A code example of this with the structure would help immensely, there really is nothing out there to do with the back end in 1.6 :(

Comment: Check my example from the link above and the location of content.tpl.
It works perfect here http://prntscr.com/3s435i

Comment: Hmm... I tried to setup as you have had in your previous example however when i try to click on the new link it says `Controller not found`. I checked the class_index file and the `AdminPageController` value is there pointing to a controller that does exist? Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I did the steps from the answer and it worked. Try again the steps and do them exactly the way they are described. You have either not created the controller or have not deleted the class_index after creating it.

Comment: Tried again with "page2". Followed the instructions exactly! But still controller not found. I am using 1.6.0.6, could there be a problem with that?

Comment: Going to try to reinstall prestashop and see if that helps, I have been fiddling and maybe broke something in the process...

Comment: The version is not a problem. Are you sure that you have created exactly this file on the same location?
controllers/admin/AdminPageController.php 
are you sure that you have deleted the class_index.php file after the controller is added? What is the "Page" page link?

Comment: The file location is exactly as stated. I deleted the class_index file after creating the new controller (without doing anything on prestashop inbetween). the link if i hover over "Page" in the catalog menu is: "`http://localhost/lcl.prestashop/prestashop/admin1557/index.php?controller=AdminPage&token=d279c42e2fb193ea43cb77a197c7a388`" and in class_index: `'AdminPageController' => array ( 'path' => 'controllers/admin/AdminPageController.php', 'type' => 'class', )`

Comment: Is the menu exactly as this one? http://prntscr.com/3s4dd1 and in that AdminPageController.php you have: <?php
class AdminPageController extends AdminController .......... ?

Comment: I was adding Catalog to the module field, so stupid a mistake! Thank you SO much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: One more question, the new menu once added does not appear in the menu list anymore, I can manually remove this from tabs in the database but any idea why?

Comment: It appears. You must click "Details" from the "Edit" dropdown of the "Catalog" row, to see the submenus of "Catalog" http://prntscr.com/3s4u6v