# How to create PrestaShop backoffice page programatically from module?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

[How to create a new page in prestashop admin panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490217/how-to-create-a-new-page-in-prestashop-admin-panel) <- this is the closest thing I found, but this question is not a duplicate.

How to create a back office module page along with it's contents (paragraph and input controls) from the module itself without the need to actually put a template file by FTP? User should need to do anything apart from installing the module to get a backoffice menu entry leading to the created page.

Comment: you want module config page or custom admin controller with a custom back office page?

Answer (score 1):

In the function install()

```
$this->installModuleTab('Name on menu (ex: My module action)', 'Module (ex: MyModule)', Tab::getIdFromClassName('name of files module (ex: myAdminModule.php)')))
```

In the module :

```
    private function installModuleTab($tabClass = null, $tabName = null, $idTabParent = 0)
    {
        $pass = true;
        $tabNameLang = array();

        if (Tab::getIdFromClassName($tabClass))
            return (true);

        @AmazonTools::copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/images/a16.gif', _PS_IMG_DIR_.'t/'.$tabClass.'.gif');

        foreach (Language::getLanguages() as $language)
            $tabNameLang[$language['id_lang']] = $tabName;

        $tab = new Tab();
        $tab->name = $tabNameLang;
        $tab->class_name = $tabClass;
        $tab->module = $this->name;
        $tab->id_parent = (int)$idTabParent;

        // For Prestashop 1.2
        //
        if (version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.3', '<'))
            $pass = $tab->add();
        else
            $pass = $tab->save();

        return ($pass);
    }
```

Regards,